# View controller (that calls another vc as a popup) in a tab bar, gets removed from tab bar hierarchy when tabs are switched

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have view controllers, embedded in a `UITabBarController`. In one of this `UIViewControllers` I have a button which calls a popup view controller (pVC). pVC's is connected to the view controller via a `UISegue` modally, and its presentation style is set to `overCurrentContext`.

It works fine. However, I have noticed that when the pVC is showing and I switch the view controller to another one through the tab bar and come back to the one with the popup, the popup is still there, but the background is black. It looks like this:

[image]

I guess, this happens because the views beneath the popup are removed from the view hierarchy. In a `view hierarchy debugger` I see that my entire view controller is removed (not just its subviews). The problem is, I don't understand why this happens when I return back to that view controller (doesn't tab bars work that way?), and why the popup is still there (maybe because it is not just a view, but a `UIViewController`). I also would like to know how to solve this issue.

If you could explain why this happens (what is happening behind this), and how to solve this, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do this if user can select with touch

```
   // UITabBarControllerDelegate
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    print("Selected view controller")

  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Or this if manually

```
   self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

   self.tabBarController(self.tabBarController!, didSelect: self)
```

any option implement **UITabBarControllerDelegate**

Comment: Should I call this code from `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method?

Comment: Sorry? My popup is just another view controller which is segued from a view controller, embedded inside a tab bar. Why I shouldn't be able to switch tabs? They are completely active (popup doesn't overlay them)

Comment: Yep and give me feedback now

Comment: Wait, your code is just changing the view controller programatically, or what?

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, the popup disappears but the view controller beneath it is still not visible when I switch the tabs back

Comment: do this only self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: please let  me know  when you click the viewController that opens the popup then what will you do ???

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, too. The result is the same as in my last comment: the views, inside of the view controller, aren't get added to the view hierarchy

Comment: It is just a popup with some labels (they contain some info). It also has a button that closes the popup. That's it.

Comment: if you open and close it then easily then where is the main problem ???

Comment: The problem is, when the popup is open, the user can still switch tabs. And when he does that and comes back, the view controller is deleted from the tab bar controller view hierarchy (I have just checked in a view hierarchy debugger that my view controller is completely removed from the tab bar (it is not just that the vc's subviews are not in a hierarchy, but the vc itself)).

Comment: it's supposed that the pop is full screen how does user switch tab when the pop up is shown ??????

Comment: tab bar is still visible. The popup doesn't cover it, but appears behind the tap bar and above the vc

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into your popupVC:

```
tabBarController.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Well, my popup is just another view controller which is called via a segue, so it's not dismissible by definition. However, it already has a button inside of it, which dismisses the popup. The problem is that the underlying view controller (from which I call the popup vc) gets removed when I switch tabs, while the popup vc is present, hence I get the black screen. But I don't know why this happens and still can't find a way to fix it

Comment: Wait, but if the popup isn't dismissable, then how can you switch tabs with the popup still being there...?

Comment: What basically happens is that in a root vc I have a table view. In the cells of the table view I have a button. When I tap the button another view controller appears on top of this one (it acts like a popup, maybe I didn't make it clear in the question, just say). Its background colour is set to `clear` and it has another `UIView` inside of it. The tab bar is still visible, so users can tap the tabs

Comment: So, this can solve the issue by making the tab bar not interaction enabled. However, I would like a more elegant solution. Currently I'm trying to hide the tab bar (I think it is a better solution, because it is not good when you see something that is intended to be intractable, but it's not, especially if it is a tab bar). Maybe you know the best way to do that?

Comment: Try this: `tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true`

Comment: Yeah, I've already found that solution. Thank you anyway for your help. But I still wonder, why there is such behaviour

Comment: Well, I would do but your answer is an answer to the part of my question. My initial question was different. It was about the reasons why black screen appears and how that can be solved. However, if you change your answer, according to your comment that is a type of solution, I would accept it. It makes other people easier to find the solution to the similar problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163149/discussion-between-vadian-and-tigran-iskandaryan).